# How to increase response timeout in application using Apollo Angular, Graphql and NestJS

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, graphql, nestjs

If I upload large amount data and files in one single api which take around 2 mins to complete, I'm receiving 504 error. But at backend the process is still ongoing, records are getting created even after frontend shows error.

There is no Response payload in 504 error.

I tried to increase the timeout at frontend nginx configuration but it gives error in deployment.

Below Frontend nginx config file gave  error: HTTP directive is not allowed here

[image: Ngnix error]

[image: Backend network error]

[image: Frontend error]

Answer (score 0):

If it happens in dev mode then you can set `"timeout": 360000` in proxy config, in prod mode there is no way to alter timeout, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34421.

If you know what you are doing then you can try to provide custom `XhrFactory` and set timeout there.